# how to replace the particular string in-between paragraph in DB2

Tags: string, replace, db2

In the below string, i need to replace the string as space (' ') which starts from DND_NCP_TEXT_START and end at DND_NCP_TEXT_END. without hardcode the string or without store it in variable. any possible using regular expression?

**String:**
'Dear DND_CST_NAME_STARTHARRIET SCOTT
:DND_CST_NAME_END
DND_NCP_NAME_STARTHARRY SHORT
:DND_NCP_NAME_END
DND_ATTORNEY_TEXT_START

Our records indicate that you represent
DND_CST_NAME_STARTHARRIET D SCOTT
DND_CST_NAME_END
DND_NCP_NAME_STARTHARRY A SHORT
DND_NCP_NAME_END in the above referenced child support matter.  Please contact your client regarding this matter and advise us as soon as possible.
If you are no longer representing
DND_CST_NAME_STARTHARRIET D SCOTT
DND_CST_NAME_END
DND_NCP_NAME_STARTHARRY A SHORT
DND_NCP_NAME_END, please file a Notice of Withdrawal.
DND_ATTORNEY_TEXT_END

'

**needed output:**
start string DND_NCP_NAME_START and end string DND_NCP_NAME_END  and string  inside this need to remove

Comment: Have you tried the [REGEXP_REPLACE scalar function](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSEPGG_11.5.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.sql.ref.doc/doc/r0061496.html)? If yes, then can you show your attempt and result?

Comment: no,I tried with hard coded string but string needs to be found and replace with space even if it is in multiple places within the paragraph. now i am trying by find the start and end position and then replace. but code need to be simple,that's why.

Comment: Use a regexp wildcard denoting any number of any characters between those 2 string constants as a regexp expression.

Comment: could be  please give me a sample code?

Comment: I tried like below       select REGEXP_REPLACE ('DND_ATTORNEY_TEXT_START Dear EDWIN Our records indicate that you represent HARRIET D SCOTT in the above referenced child support matter.
DND_NCP_TEXT_START Please contact your client regarding this matter and advise us as soon as possible.DND_NCP_TEXT_END Please co-operate.DND_NCP_TEXT_START Please contact your client regarding this matter and advise us as soon as possible.DND_NCP_TEXT_END We are anticipating your reply. Thanks a lot. DND_ATTORNEY_TEXT_END'
,'DND_NCP_TEXT_START(.*)DND_NCP_TEXT_END','',1,0) FROM SYSIBM.SYSDUMMY1

Comment: but it removed the string "Please co-operate" also

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem of your expression is, that you have 2 such patterns in the text, but since the default algorithm used is greedy one, the whole string starting from the 1-st `DND_NCP_TEXT_START` and ending with **the last** `DND_NCP_TEXT_END` is removed.
Use non-greedy matching (`.*?`) as in the example below.

```
SELECT 
REGEXP_REPLACE 
(
 'DND_ATTORNEY_TEXT_START Dear EDWIN Our records indicate that you represent HARRIET D SCOTT in the above referenced child support matter. DND_NCP_TEXT_START Please contact your client regarding this matter and advise us as soon as possible.DND_NCP_TEXT_END Please co-operate.DND_NCP_TEXT_START Please contact your client regarding this matter and advise us as soon as possible.DND_NCP_TEXT_END We are anticipating your reply. Thanks a lot. DND_ATTORNEY_TEXT_END'
,'DND_NCP_TEXT_START.*?DND_NCP_TEXT_END',''
) 
FROM SYSIBM.SYSDUMMY1;
```

Comment: for the above string it works. But actual sting will be like xml structure (xml converted into string). So it is not working. I  have updated the actual string in the question part bro.

Comment: There are no `DND_NCP_TEXT_START` and `DND_NCP_TEXT_END` constants in your new text. There are `DND_NCP_NAME_START` and `DND_NCP_NAME_END`instead. Another wrong string? What statement is not working exactly?

Comment: DND_NCP_NAME_START and DND_NCP_NAME_END is the actual constant. actually xml converted into string. inside that, i have the constants like above. whatever character (/,\,",: etc,.)inside the those constants(including constants) should be removed.  but for updated string the pattern 'DND_NCP_NAME_START.*?DND_NCP_NAME_END' is not working.

Comment: What's the problem with the result at this [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=db2_11.1&fiddle=a90884d7b17b09264cefc20612e8f239) link?

Comment: The below string only i updated. but after click the save, the string changed as you are seeing now in the question part. that is the pbm.

Comment: <p xml:space="preserve" style="TNR_12">Dear DND_CST_NAME_START<u><var name="root.cst_fl_name" type="string">HARRIET SCOTT</var></u>:DND_CST_NAME_ENDDND_NCP_NAME_START<u><var name="root.ncp_first_name" type="string">HARRY</var> <var name="root.ncp_last_name" type="string">SHORT</var></u>:DND_NCP_NAME_ENDDND_ATTORNEY_TEXT_START</p>
                        <p xml:space="preserve" style="lineheight_15" />
                        <p xml:space="preserve" style="TNR_12">Our records indicate that you represent DND_CST_NAME_START<var name="root.cst_full_name" type="string">HARRIET D

Comment: SCOTT</var>DND_CST_NAME_ENDDND_NCP_NAME_START<var name="root.ncp_full_name" type="string">HARRY A SHORT</var>DND_NCP_NAME_END in the above referenced child support matter.  Please contact your client regarding this matter and advise us as soon as possible.  If you are no longer representing DND_CST_NAME_START<var name="root.cst_full_name" type="string">HARRIET D SCOTT</var>DND_CST_NAME_ENDDND_NCP_NAME_START<var name="root.ncp_full_name" type="string">HARRY A SHORT</var>DND_NCP_NAME_END, please file a Notice of Withdrawal.DND_ATTORNEY_TEXT_END</p>

Comment: Once again. Follow the [db<>fiddle2](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=db2_11.1&fiddle=459d59cde27278fff45cfe7fbe1dba16) link. Run the statement and say, what's wrong with the result. You may edit the statement with your own constants and share your link here with the description of what you want and what you unexpectedly get.

Comment: Extremely sorry. that was my mistakes. Code works perfectly. Thanks a lot.